# $\|T\| \neq \sup_{\|h\|=1} |\langle Th,h\rangle |$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Finding difficulty in giving an example:

> An operator in B(H) such that $\|T\| \neq \sup_{\|h\|=1} |\langle Th,h\rangle |$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equality holds for selfadjoints. The typical candidate for a counterexample is then the canonical non-normal operator, $$T=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix} .$$
It is easy to check that $\|T\|=1$, but $|\langle Th,h\rangle|\leq1/2$ for all $h$ with $\|h\|=1$.